# Where is Shemelincsi, Volynsk guberniya in Russia?

Tags: palaeography, russia, historical-gazetteer, ukraine

I'm trying to determine where in Russia the town/city from the passenger list actually is located in Russia today - below pic is for the passenger "Belinsky" showing contact and town/city for 1911 arrival in NY on the SS Birma from Libau Russia to NY. Appears to read "Shemelincsi" Volynsk guberniya. Unable to locate on any map.

[image: From passenger list under person and city/town where one came from]

[image]

Added above after original post It shows the place of birth of 3 close relatives from Draft Registration Cards - thought it may help

Comment: Do you know Belinsky's religion? (I'm wondering if it could be a Jewish shtetl.)

Comment: I do not know for a fact their religious background - the name is Stephandia Belinsky or Belinskaja as per Ellis Island. Under the Race /people heading they answered Russian while some others answered Hebrew. Any help or advice how to in finding out if they were Jewish/Hebrew would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The best match that I could find is 'Shemetitsa' from the [JewishGen Gazetteer](https://www.jewishgen.org/databases/gazetteer/gazetteer.php).

It is listed as a 'populated place' with coordinates 51° 03'N 28° 26'E, which would place it within the [Volhynian governorate](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Volhynian_governorate_1820.jpg) in the north of modern Ukraine, about 2km SE of [Luhyny](https://www.jewishgen.org/communities/community.php?usbgn=-1045139).

I've looked for it with a number of online maps, including [mapcarta](https://mapcarta.com/es/13734140), and [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Luhyny,+Zhytomyr+Oblast,+Ukraine/@51.086941,28.363509,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47297cb0e03a5637:0x5531c82197a98e13!8m2!3d51.0836752!4d28.4004787) and there doesn't seem to be much there today.

Mapire have an [historical map of the area around Luhyny](https://mapire.eu/en/geoname/ukraine/luhyny-702679/). The map doesn't have a scale, and the place names use a Cyrillic script (plus the tape joining the sections of the map is irritating), but there is a settlement to the south-east of Luhyny that may be Shemetitsa.

[image: map]

What's written on the card may be an attempt to 'Anglicise' the place name to allow it to be written in the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked out the names of villages and towns on the map of Volhynian Governorate (Volynskaya guberniya) and I suppose that the most close to them are Lyakhovtsy ("Lachowcy")
https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%80%27%D1%8F
and Jukovtsy ("Jukowcy").
https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96
The last one I can't decode for now. Do you understand what is written?

[image]

About the first image:
Belinsky Shemelinsky. Probably it is double surname and was written as Belinsky-Shemelinsky. For polish origin it was normal. As well as for noble people. There were nobles with the same surname in Volynskaya gubernia.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5

You need to find the documents about your ancestors to check out who they were.

Here you can check out all the places of this guberniya:
https://www.wdl.org/ru/item/14073/view/1/1/